# Nopcommerce export user roles

Tags: nopcommerce

I'm trying to get a list of ALL user roles for each user through the nopcommerce database. i just need the Customer.Id, Customer.Username, Customer.Email and Customer.Role (some have multiple roles)

This is all jacked up.

```
SELECT Customer.Id, Customer.Username, Customer.Email, CustomerRole.Name
FROM ((Customer
INNER JOIN CustomerRole ON CustomerRole.Id = Customer.Id)
INNER JOIN Customer_CustomerRole_Mapping ON Customer_CustomerRole_Mapping.CustomerRole_Id = CustomerRole.Id)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think i might have figured it out.... This seems to have worked. there are multiple rows for the same id however that is ok i think. it'd be nice to aggregate the 'CustomerRole.Name' into one row but i'll make it work. 


    SELECT DISTINCT Customer.Id, Customer.Username, Customer.Email, CustomerRole.Id, CustomerRole.Name, Customer_CustomerRole_Mapping.CustomerRole_Id
    FROM ((Customer
    INNER JOIN Customer_CustomerRole_Mapping ON Customer_CustomerRole_Mapping.Customer_Id= Customer.Id)
    INNER JOIN CustomerRole ON CustomerRole.Id = Customer_CustomerRole_Mapping.CustomerRole_Id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need a LEFT OTUER JOIN because in your DB can be user without role; in this case you can use this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CUST.Id, CUST.Username, CUST.Email, CR.Id, CR.Name, 
CCRM.CustomerRole_Id ,
FROM CUSTOMER CUST
LEFT OUTER JOIN Customer_CustomerRole_Mapping CCRM
ON CUST.ID = CCRM.Customer_Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN CustomerRole CR
ON CCRM.CustomerRole_Id = CR.Id
```

Also, you can have only one row per user with a column with his roles, like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CUST.Id, CUST.Username, CUST.Email,
Roles = STUFF((
        SELECT ',' + CAST(CR1.Name as varchar(4000))
        FROM CustomerRole CR1
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Customer_CustomerRole_Mapping CCRM1
            ON CCRM1.CustomerRole_Id = CR1.Id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN CUSTOMER CUST1
            ON CUST1.ID = CCRM1.Customer_Id
        WHERE CUST1.Id = CUST.Id
        FOR XML PATH('')
     ), 1, 1, '')
FROM CUSTOMER CUST
LEFT OUTER JOIN Customer_CustomerRole_Mapping CCRM
ON CUST.ID = CCRM.Customer_Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN CustomerRole CR
ON CCRM.CustomerRole_Id = CR.Id
```

Depending of your using, last query can be a little bit slow if you have a lot of customers.

Comment: Thank you for this!!!!

Comment: Please accept and close topic if I have resolve your problem. Thanks.

Comment: how to i close it?